# Spring Data JPA custom repository query not returning anything

Tags: java, jpa, repository

```
public class Foo{
   private String foo;
   private String bar;
   //class methods
}

public List<Foo> findByFooBarContains(@Param("bar")String bar) {
   TypedQuery<Foo> query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT foo FROM Foo foo WHERE foo.bar LIKE '%:bar%'", Foo.class);
   return query.getResultList();
}
```

I've tested with JPA standard findByName contains and it is working as it should. However my custom query is returning nothing. what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a JPA repository interface, you can simply define a [query method](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods) like:

```
public interface FooRepo extends JpaRepository<FooRepo, String>{
  
  //Query Method
  List<Foo> findByBarContains(String bar);

}
```

You can then call this method from your Service like:

```
@Service
public class FooService {

    @Autowired
    private FooRepo fooRepo;

    public List<Foo> fetchByBarContains(String bar){
        return fooRepo.findByBarContains(bar);
    }

}
```

You can also implement [native or JPQL queries](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query) by defining them in your Repository like:

```
//JPQL (foo here is your model and not the table)
@Query("SELECT foo FROM Foo WHERE bar LIKE %?1%")
List<Foo>findByBarContains(String bar);

//Native
@Query(
  value = "SELECT foo FROM Foo WHERE bar LIKE %?1%", 
  nativeQuery = true)
  List<Foo>findByBarContains(String bar);
```

Of course, your model should be Annotated with @Entity like:

```
@Entity(name="Foo")
public class Foo{
    
   @Id
   private String foo;
   
   //Use @Column annotation if your database column has a different name than your field
   @Column(name = "BAR")
   private String bar;
    // getters and setters
    
}
```

On the other hand, if you want to use entity manager, you can do:

```
public List<Foo> findByFooBarContains(String bar) {
return entityManager.createQuery(
    "SELECT foo FROM Foo foo WHERE foo.bar LIKE %:bar%", Foo.class)
    .setParameter("bar", bar)
    .getResultList();
}
```

I think the **".setParameter("bar", bar)"** is what you're missing in your code.

Comment: made sense. tried it out, it failed on org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Could not locate named parameter [name], expecting one of []. The repository is set and the JPARepository findByContains methods are working, so the data is being persisted properly. I'm implementing a custo repo which needs his own findByContains, that's why i'm doing it

Comment: Well, if you want a different query, why don't you create one with different name on your Repo? Anyway, did this one work?

public List<Foo> findByFooBarContains(String bar) {
    TypedQuery<Foo> query = getEntityManager().createQuery("SELECT foo FROM 
     Foo foo WHERE foo.bar LIKE %:bar%", Foo.class);
     query.setParameter("bar", bar);
     return query.getResultList();
}
If not, try to remove the %% to see if you get any results

Comment: it named somethingl ike findByFooBarNameContains or something like that. That one didn't work. The %% is required by HQL I believe. at least all the guides i've found on how to create like queries required it... i'll give it a go when i have the change